# How to pass a Python pandas function as a variable/parameter in another function?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

def func_sum(df, cols, col):
    res = df[cols].groupby(col).sum()
    return res

def func_count(df, cols,col):
    res = df[cols].groupby(col).count()
    return res

def func_ave(df, cols, col):
    res = df[cols].groupby(col).mean()
    return res
```

The way I did to combine these three functions is like below, which is not very elegant.

```
def func(df, cols, col, method):
    if method == 'sum':
        return df[cols].groupby(col).sum()
    if method == 'count':
        return df[cols].groupby(col).count()
    if method == 'mean':
        return df[cols].groupby(col).mean()
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do this without using IF ELSE statement. 
How Can I Pass the function of (sum, count, or mean) as a variable and then let's the passed function variable to be called inside the main 'func' function.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), which takes one or more functions by reference or by name.

For example:

```
def func(df, cols, col, method):
    return df[cols].groupby(col).agg(method)

func(df, cols, col, pd.Series.sum)
func(df, cols, col, 'count')
func(df, cols, col, np.mean)
```

Comment: It is good to learn about pandas' agg function. Thanks a lot!